# Changes from SVG files only reflect from the last executed SVG file

Tags: vue.js, svg

I have 3 SVG files and I displaying those files by using `v-html="output_here"` when SVG displayed, I will hide some of the elements of it, for example I will hide the path. What happened is the last rendered SVG file only changed.

Output:
[image]
if you will see in the photo the "inter 2" only hide its PATH but the remaining 2 didn't hide the path.

Note: 2 of the SVG files are same content and 1 is different & the component is included inside loop

Here's my code:

```
<template>
    <div>
         <div v-html="output_here" v-if="output_here"></div>
    </div>
</template>
mounted(){
 this.output_here = window.atob(data)
 setTimeout(() => {
        this.hideLantern()
 }, 1000)
},
methods: {
 hideLantern(){
       Object.keys(document.querySelectorAll(`#Signals`)[0].children).map(key =>{
          let parent_id = document.querySelectorAll(`#Signals`)[0].children[key].id
          if (parent_id) {
                document.getElementById(parent_id).style.display="none"
          }
      })
 }
}
```

Comment: do you have elements with duplicate id values on the composite page?

Comment: I actually update my code to ```<div v-html="output_here" :id="output_here" v-if="output_here"></div>``` to have unique element. but the output still the same. @RobertLongson

Comment: i don't have duplicate id from composite page.

Comment: @RobertLongson should i put id from <defs> inside svg file?

Comment: You should edit the question to include the SVG files. i.e. provide a [mcve] - something we can run ourselves if we want to.